# Trying to learn the "one letter off" encryption technique

Tags: java

This is a small portion of homework where I have to scan whole files of text and encrypt/decrypt the whole thing, but I figure that I should be able to understand the basics before I jump in to trying to do that with multiple words.

I'm trying to figure out why my code only changes the last letter of the word I am trying to encrypt instead of each letter of the whole word.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Encryptor
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String word = "";
  char ch = ' ';

  System.out.println("What word do you want to encrypt");
  word = in.nextLine();

  //Encrypt word
  for(int i = 0; i<word.length();i++)
  {
     ch = word.charAt(i);
     ch++;
  }

  System.out.println(ch);


}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning `word.charAt(i);` to `ch` and then incrementing `ch`. However this does not change the value of `word`. To do so you could do the following:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = "";
StringBuilder encrypedWordSB = new StringBuilder();

System.out.println("What word do you want to encrypt");
word = in.nextLine();

// Encrypt word
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    char ch = word.charAt(i);
    ch++;

    encrypedWordSB.append(ch);
}

System.out.println(encrypedWordSB);
```

In the example above we encrypt the character `ch` inside the `for` loop, and then append the encrypted character to a string. After the `for` loop we have the String `encryptedWord` with all of the encrypted characters.

Comment: I accept that this a "basic"/"learner", but I'd still recommend a `StringBuilder` over `String` concatenation, but that's me ;)

Comment: Fair enough! I've updated the answer, it's a good idea to learn that aswell.

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening in your code is that you, inside the for loop, select the chart at that index and increase it. But that's all you do in the loop, you don't save or display it anywhere. So when the next iteration of the loop comes around it overrides this value. Then after the loop you display the result, and since the last letter is the last one the iteration processes that is the one you display.

You can fix this problem by creating an empty string before the loop, and in the iteration add every char to this string. Than after the loop you display this string.